# ES6: What does "import $ from 'jquery'" really means?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, atom-editor

I assumed at first that it simply means, load the jQuery module and initialize it in a variable called $.

But then, by using Atom with the atom-typescript, I got an error saying that it "Cannot find module 'jquery'". Even though all the code works in the browser, it looks like atom-typescript can't resolve anything looking like import x from y.

Now, looking at ES6 doc, I found out that you import a class/function from a module. The meaning is totally different, and it makes sense with for example this:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
```

But then what does it mean in the case of jQuery?

I am probably mixing different issues in the same one but any explanation would clear this confusion, so thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: The bit of information you're missing is regarding `default` exports from modules. You also need to have a TypeScript definition for jQuery in your project.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export

Answer (score 3):

The statement `import $ from jquery` pretty much amounts to dependency injection. Just like one would write `import React from 'react'` to give oneself access to the React library within a file, so to can one write `import $ from jquery`. (In case it's throwing you off, the dollar sign is used because jQuery and its methods are accessed using the dollar (*a.k.a.* jQuery) operator.

As for the errors being thrown, that could be several things:

1. If you separately installed jQuery as a dependency in your *package.json* file as well as included a `<script>` tag from a jQuery CDN, this error will be thrown. If you're usage of jQuery is through NPM, then the `import $ from jquery` syntax is correct/necessary. If you intend to use jQuery through a CDN (as I would recommend), the `import` statement is unnecessary. (Since you've included that script tag in your *index.html*, you have access to jQuery and its library throughout the scope of your application). Do not, however, do both.
2. Also note that in the case of the `import { Component } from 'angular2/core';` statement, something slightly different is going on. Namely, one is importing the **named export** *Component*, as per the ([AMD specification](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html). You can think of it, in this case, as importing only a part of the larger Angular2 core library when the entire library would be unnecessary.

Just to be sure, check that you have actually given yourself access to jQuery through either a CDN or by installing it as an NPM dependency.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I am trying to create a clean bootstrap for all this, and it's available here: https://github.com/jordymeow/meowbs-2016. You can have a look. jQuery is not included at the moment, but atom-typescript is also showing the same errors for all the modules (especially the Angular ones). I am missing something but I have not idea what...